# Trained YOLO, which iteration does yolo_best.weights have?

Tags: yolo

I trained YOLOv3 via the Darknet framework. Every 1000 iteration it saved the weights but at the end, Darknet evaluates all the weights, and uses the best. They are saved in a separate file "yolov3_best.weights".

I want to find out, which iteration was used for this file. I tried so far:

- use the weights in a recognition test via terminal and checked the output
- opened the best.weights-file via Editor and searched for it

but I couldn't find it.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks upfront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, it is not clear how to find out which iteration step / epoch was used for the best_weights-file, so I did the following:

I wrote a script, which uses the "yolov3_best.weights"-file to detect all classes in the testset, compared that with my label-data and calculated the metrics recall, precision and f1.
I did this also for all the other weights, that darknet saves by default (every 1000 iteration steps) and compared the results of.

At the end I found out, that the "yolov3_best.weights" is not the best for my metrics, so I choose the one with the highest recall value (but others may choose according to the metric that has to be optimized for the case neccessary).

Hope this helpes others.

Answer (score 0):

From [AlexeyAB wiki](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) there are two ways of doing this

1. Test the various weights in `backup/` using the `map` `recall` flag.

   Example:
   `./detector map data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg backup/yolo-obj_7000.weights`

   Do this for all the weights and pick one with the **highest mAP (mean average precision) or IoU (intersect over union)**
2. Train with the `-map` flag

   Example: `./detector detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -map`

   `mAP` will be calculated for every 4 Epochs using `valid=valid.txt` file that is specified in `data/obj.data`